# Deep Neural Network Weight's Evaluation

Tags: deep-learning, theano, keras, conv-neural-network, theano-cuda

I am using Theano with keras. I have a trained DNN and I have dumped the weight's in a file. I am performing some operations on these weights and again dumping the new converted weights into another file.

Now, I am loading my DNN model with these converted weights and want to compare the results between the two.

I used the keras.evaluate method but I find the accuracy to be exactly same even though the weights are different.

Is there another approach with which I can compare the accuracy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras performs some under the hood operations for your batch_size including normalization. So if you only scaled and translated your image the result will stay the same.

Anyways you can do `model.predict(sample, 1)` and write your own evaluation metric  to circumvent this issue.

Comment: I basically reduced some decimal places to lower computation load. And, now trying to figure out the loss in the accuracy due to the conversion to values with reduced decimal place.